# How to get the quote address object when user logged in?

Tags: magento-1.7, quote, address

One particular user logged in to his account from frontend and adds some items to the shopping cart. And then he logged out. And again when he logged in I want to get his quote address object.

How to achieve this? Is there any event which fires and I can get the quote address object? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To get a customer's default billing adress you can do the following:

```
<?php
$customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
$visitorData = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
$billingaddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($visitorData->default_billing);
$addressdata = $billingaddress ->getData();
$addressdata['street'];
$addressdata['city'];
$addressdata['postcode'];
$addressdata['region'];
$addressdata['telephone'];

var_dump($addressdata);
```

Comment: I was asking about quote address object. Not the customer billing address.

Comment: From what I understood, he didn't actually order anything right? He just put some items on the shopping cart and logged out. If that's the case, there's no quote address to get, only his default address that the customer filled when signing up.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is listen to `customer_customer_authenticated` then get the `quote_address`:

```
$quote = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/quote_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->getFirstItem();

if($quote) {
    $quote->getBillingAddress(); // quote billing address object
    $quote->getShippingAddress(); // quote shipping address object
}
```

if you are using the multi checkout you want to use `getAllShippingAddresses()` and maybe the method `getAllAddresses()` on `$quote` is interesting for you.